# Unable to create converter for class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Retrofit Documentation says:

"By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's **ResponseBody**...Converters can be added to support other types"

This implies I should be able to make a api call **WIHTOUT using the GSON converter**, and get my response in the form of a "ResponseBody" object.

but I still get error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
```

here is my code

```
    @GET("v1/search")
    Call<ResponseBody> getArtists(@Query("q") String name, @Query("type") String searchType);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.spotify.com/")
                    .build();

    api = retrofit.create(SpotifyApi.class);

    api.getArtists(searchBox.getText().toString(), "artist")
                             .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                                 }

                                 @Override
                                 public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                                 }
                             });
```

Basically for I want to be able to use Retrofit in its purest/simplest form and just get a basic/raw response back. this is not for a real app, it's for experimentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `okhttp3.ResponseBody` from OkHttp 3.x (which Retrofit depends on). That error message indicates you are using the type from OkHttp 2.x.

Comment: omg you're amazing! I would really appreciate if you explained how you figured that out

Comment: I wrote Retrofit 2 and contribute to OkHttp 3 :)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out immediately after I wrote that haha, thank you so much, you guys are the best!